# Supported Guest OS on Ubuntu OpenStack

Tags: openstack

Is there a definitive list of guest operating systems officially supported on Ubuntu OpenStack?

Not looking for what OpenStack can be installed on. Looking for what OSes can be run as an Instance on Ubuntu OpenStack and is in a supported Guest OS  matrix.

Comment: What is wrong with the official stance here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive ?

Comment: Thanks, however, that a list Ubuntu OS supporting the installation of OpenStack. I'm looking for supported OSes as guests deployed as instances on top of OpenStack KVM.

Answer (score 2):

[Openstack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive) will only support LTS and only current versions. So, at this time that is 14.04, 16.04 and 18.04. Nothing else (12.04 has an extended support cycle but has gone end of life for us normal mortals; I would assume if you are a paying customer 12.04 is also still supported).

Including the not released 20.04 LTS, the following graphic from [ubuntu.com](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) shows the support for all the LTS releases (orange):

[image: Ubuntu support lifecycle]

Answer (score 0):

openstack works on multiple hypervisors, and the question is usually going to rely on which hypervisor is in use in the stack.
https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/config-reference/compute/hypervisors.html

I am also trying to find out if openstack will run on a low-latency kernel, and in turn run ubuntu studio as a guest OS, and was able to find matrices like you are requesting, but they are few and far between and are ~always~ vendor specific, i.e., RedHat or Oracle have them.